# Sort blocks of text chronologically in MS Word

Tags: sorting, ms-word, date-sorting

Does anyone know a way of sorting blocks of text chronologically in MS Word?

There will be a section heading (H1 style) including text with a date, then a varying number of paragraphs (normal style) and then another H1 etc.
So I need sort the heading plus all it's associated text through the whole document.
Here's an example:

**Markham and Ellesmere x-ray of left wrist, January 2, 2007**

Normal examination

**Marksville x-ray and ultrasound, March 28, 2007**

History:  pain.  Query gallbladder calculus.

Abdominal ultrasound

Interpretation:  normal

Does this makes sense?

Comment: As they say, I would not start from here. Why not a database or Excel? Either will link up well with Word.

Comment: The documents are in Word, not excel or a db.  Is there a quick way of converting them to an appropriate format, sorting them and then saving as Word?  Or any other suggestions bearing in mind that they are in Word.

Comment: You could run through the documents using VBA and Excel or Access ( Access would be easier) using the headers as markers. I have done this myself with a set of 700 odd documents and it was not fun. The headings were not always headings, sometimes they were text formatted to look like a heading, so there was a good deal of manual checking involved.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I have applied the styles, so at least they will be consistent.  I have no knowledge of VBA or Access, and no idea what this involves.

Comment: You might be able to do something with Word XML and a database of your choice.

Comment: OK, that still sounds pretty vague...But thanks for your suggestion.  I would appreciate any links to actual step by step instructions or other help.

Comment: If I was prepared to provide details, I would have answered, not commented. The question remains open so it may yet attract an answer, but to me, it seems too broad to get real answer, for me, the amount of work to answer would be more like a job that just help along the way. Here is a link, for what it is worth: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb266220(v=office.12).aspx